# DevStack unable to ping from VM

Tags: openstack, devstack

I've searched for this but unable to resolve the issue. I am using a vagrant script to set up devstack on a Ubuntu 14.04. I clone the stable/juno branch and run the ./stack.sh command. However, when I launch a cirros instance, I cannot ping it from inside the VM. The cirros instance gets an IP of 10.0.0.2. The VM has a br100 interface with an IP of 10.0.0.1. However, when I log into the cirros using the web interface, I get an IP of 10.0.2.16. This makes no sense as the dashboard shows a different IP. I have enabled the ICMP before you suggest that is the issue. I have also allocated a floating IP which starts with 172.24.4.1. I don't see any interface on my VM that has a similar IP and hence can't ping with that IP either.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, did you solve it?

Comment: I haven't got this issue in a while. I use OpenStack Kilo and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This can maybe help solving the problem:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: I use this command all the time and it helps me get internet working via NAT on the VM. No luck with the actual issue at the time though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you're using Virtualbox.
My suggestion, set mode bridge to the NIC and use a simple local.conf, some thing like:

```
IP_VERSION=4
HOST_IP=192.168.1.100
FLOATING_RANGE="192.168.1.224/27"
Q_FLOATING_ALLOCATION_POOL=start=192.168.1.226,end=192.168.1.254
```

The others VirtualBox modes are more complex to configure traffic in/out.